# What is the fastest way to create multiple thousands of users on a system?

Tags: linux, users, performance

I need to create multiple thousands of users on a linux system. Currently I use the `newusers` command with a file as the source for all the users. The file contains around 10000 users. Running

```bsh
$ newusers /tmp/users.txt
```

works and creates the users, but it takes very long to complete.
The users don't need a shell, a home directory or a password. They also don’t need to be able to login. The users are needed for ssh tunnel purposes.

Is there a way to do this more quick?

Comment: Probably not an answer: import them into LDAP.

Comment: This is really not an answer since I need the users on the system for ssh purposes. I’ll update the question thank you!

Comment: That is the best advice for that number of users actually. Setting ldap for authentication

Comment: I don’t need authentification other than a ssh key

Comment: Have you thought about doing it the hard way? Take your user list, add the passwd fields to each user, then append that to the passwd file. You then make their homes using the original file with their list of names, copying /etc/skel over if needed. Absolutely not sure if that is faster than newusers.

Comment: I checked the passwd file and it seems that newusers still creates a password hash even when I don’t want a password for the users. Might this hashing be the reason for the long creation time? The 10000 users take like 5 minutes to create.

Comment: @number9 this might be faster! Especially since I don’t need any home directories and therefore no copying of /etc/skel

Comment: How often do you need to add 10000 users if 5 minutes is too long a time?

Comment: @p0fi if you need an ssh key for authentication, how is it you think you don't need a home directory? That said, I completely agree that you don't need a skel home directory setup, just /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: @EdGrimm because the user just needs to exist for a reverse ssh tunnel. The authorized_keys file in the home dir is not needed since the key lookup is done via a AuthorizedKeysCommand in a database

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I would do it, since they are all local accounts:

1. Determine the range of userIDs
2. Determine the group ID(s) for the users
3. Write a script that will:
   a. create a temporary password file filled with the information you need:

   ```
   ${username}:x:${userid}:${groupid}::${homedir}:/bin/false
   ```

   b. create a temporary shadow file with the information you need:

   ```
   ${username}:!!:1:0:99999:7:::
   ```
4. append the temporary shadow file to /etc/shadow and the temporary password file to /etc/passwd

NB1: I am not sure if the `${homedir}` can be blank, `/dev/null`, or something else
NB2: If you are not using `/etc/shadow`, replace the `:x:` in passwd with `:!!:`

That ought to be fairly quick (however long it takes to create the temp files), quickly update passwd & shadow files without any other password hashing, UID searching, etc.

Comment: ${homedir} cannot be blank, but it can be `/`.  The maximum password age *can* be blank, however, and then there's no password aging.  (This should only ever be done if there's no valid password, as in this case.)

Comment: And all that will take less than the five minutes described by the OP as _too long_? Your answer works but it's trying to solve a problem that isn't reasonable